# Custom community error page to show "URL no longer exist"

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, partner-communities

I have created a custom community with and used custom vf pages. Here when i trying enter wrong URL its redirecting me to OOTB page with message "URL no longer exist" but i want it to be shown on custom vf page.

portal landing page - https://testsandbox-test.cs62.force.com/agent/home
URL entered to generate error - https://testsandbox-test.cs62.force.com/agent/home2

Please help me to resolve the mentioned use case.

Thanks,

Dildar Hussain

Comment: Check base URL of your community, It might be the case that you'd be missing the prefix in URL.

Comment: portal landing page - https://testsandbox-test.cs62.force.com/agent/home
URL entered to generate error - https://testsandbox-test.cs62.force.com/agent/home2

Comment: It gives same error for both URLs?

Comment: no, first one is working fine but for second i need to handle the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the reason why my custom error page was not loading, along with assigning custom VF pages under site error page we also need to enable a setting under community preferences.

Thanks all for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Glad you figured out.

Answer (score 1):

In your site settings, there is a section called Error pages. You can click Page Assignment button and reassign your own custom VF page there. As shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lance,

i tried it and set a common error page for all error condition but still it is redirecting me to OOTB page.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Setup > Sites > Open your site by clicking the name of your community > Go to Error Pages section > Click Page Assignment button and assign you VF Error page.
2. Go to All Sites > Workspace next to your community name > Administration > Preferences > Select Use custom Visualforce error pages, then click Save

Done.

You should be able to see your custom VF error page in your community.

More details you can find here: https://salesforceprofs.com/custom-community-error-page/